# PyCharm or Mercurial error: Number of lines annotated by Mercurial is not equal to number of lines in the file

Tags: mercurial, pycharm

When I click on Annotate, I often get this message in PyCharm 2018.2.5 (running on Ubuntu 18.04):

> Number of lines annotated by Mercurial is not equal to number of lines
>   in the file. Check file econding and line separators

It looks like a Mercurial error, but in command line, the following command on the same file is succesful:

```
# hg annotate -ud <file>
```

Line enconding is `LF`, File encoding is `UTF-8`

**EDIT**

Mercurial version:

```
# hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.5.3)
```

**The file I'm try to annotate is in a subrepository**, and checking the logs I discovered
PyCharm is trying to annotate using the father's repo.
If I execute the command in father's directory, I get an empty result.
So the error is misleading, and apparently I don't know how to set up PyCharm in this case.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What Mercurial version do you have?

Comment: 4.5.3, I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Hmm that appears to be problem of PyCharm than Mercurial.  Did you try this option?  `Ignore whitespace differences in annotations` - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-version-control-mercurial.html

Comment: I did try that, but if you see my new edit, it's a different problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see.  I'm no PyCharm expert, I'll gladly leave this for someone who is.

Comment: Please file an issue [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY), the developer who is responsible for the Mercurial support would help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it. I think it makes sense answering my own question.

The structure of my project is the following:

- Project root (no VCS)

  - RepoDir (hg repository)

    - SubRepoDir (hg subrepository)

In this configuration something confuses PyCharm, and subrepositories at third level
won't be recognized.

The following works pretty well:

- RepoDir as Project root (hg repository)

  - SubRepoDir (hg subrepository)

If other directories are needed, one can add them as content root.